# Keeping men's razor blades sharp for traveling

Tags: tips-and-tricks, hygiene, packing

When I'm at home I use a double edged safety razor to shave. TSA won't let me fly with safety razors, so when I travel I use a Mach 3 razor.

My problem is that when I open a package of Mach 3 razors and use them only for my relatively infrequent travels (mostly short business overnights, some longer vacation travel), the whole package is oxidized and dull by the time I make a second trip so I waste most of the package.

I've looked for individually packaged razors but have only found cheap disposables in bulk packs of 500.

What's a good way to keep travel razors around without them getting dull before they're ever used?

Comment: You might posisbly have gotten a better answer at https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ... for instance, see @ZachSaucier 's answer to [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/keep-razor-usable-longer/13353#13353)

Comment: ... and [this link](http://lifehacker.com/5502841/extend-the-life-of-your-razor-blades-with-your-forearm), from @Floyd#s answer to the same question

Comment: You could try *carefully* smearing a little petroleum jelly on the unused blades. That should stop them oxidizing but wouldn't cause trouble when you start to use them.

Comment: Depending on the profile of the razor you may be able to "hone" the edge well enough to re-enliven them. If accessible to honing you should try PAPER (!!!) as a honing surface - smooth glossy paper or A4 printer type paper are liable to be OK. It actually works - although how well and for how many iterations may depend on the metal used. [I found that trick in an astounding  **must-read** WW2 biography by Spencer Chapman - "The Jungle is neutral". 3+ years behind Japanese lines in Malaya with no supply of nw razor blades.

Comment: How do you know a blade has oxidized? It takes me a year to use up a package of mach3 blades. In that time I've never noticed anything, but I am not especially picky about the perfection of my shave.

Comment: In my case, I know because the shave feels rough and sometimes nicks. It doesn't have that "new blade" smoothness that it should

Comment: I am picky about the perfection of my shave and I had the same exact problem as the OP. All I did was, go to Costco, got a giant bag of cheap disposable safety razors, took the packaging apart and put all of the razors in a gallon-ziplock bag. I take 2-3 with me every time I fly. After three years, I still haven't run out of that first pack I bought from Costco, and I haven't noticed any degradation of the razor blades. Yes, it depends on which part of the country you live in (how dry/humid it is) but it has worked well wherever I have lived.

Comment: Put your safety razors in checked luggage. Source: [TSA - What can I bring? - Sharp objects](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/sharp-objects)

Comment: [Store them under a pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_power)

Comment: That is amazing

Comment: I guess I'm missing something obvious here but isn't the [Mach 3](https://gillette.com/en-us/products/razors-trimmers-and-blades/mach3-razors) also a [safety razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_razor)? Why can you travel with the Mach 3 and not your own? What's the difference between them?

Comment: It's a good question, I had to look it up. I use what is called a double edged safety razor, more info below. I'll update the question. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_razor

Comment: @terdon Colloquially, "safety razor" means the kind with removable blades, versus disposable razors or cartridge razors, where the individual blades are not removable.

Comment: @wjandrea Ah! OK, that makes more sense now.

Comment: @terdon a "safety razor" is a safer alternative to a straight razor. I don't know which is more likely to nick you, but I am pretty sure that you can't kill yourself or anyone else with a safety razor properly installed in its handle. However, it would take some real effort to kill yourself or someone else with a cartridge razor. Even though a cartridge razor is surely safer, the safety razor was the safest option a century or two ago, so that's what they're still called today.

Comment: @stannius You can't kill anyone with a blade that is inside the safety razor, but you can make quite a good weapon taking the blade out and sticking it into something else. The 9/11 hijackers worked with box-cutters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thank you for all the great suggestions. Here's the solution I found that works well for me. I bought a pack of original Gillette Venus women's razors, which come individually packaged in sets of 4+. They fit the Mach 3 just fine. Whenever I go on a trip I toss one or two in my dopp kit and have the confidence that they will be fresh when I open them. They also have the advantage of taking up less space than a cartridge of Mach 3 razors.

The original Venus have a slightly larger bevel than the Mach 3, but they don't have all of the extra foaming moisturizer strips of the later Venus models (which are unpleasant on the face and much clumsier to work with)

Be aware that the blade angle on women's razors is slightly different than on men's. I haven't found this to be a problem but YMMV

[image: razor packages]

Comment: Great solution, but I need to ask: why not just by your razors at your destination? It's a rather universal product.

Comment: Someone else also suggested this, see that thread. But the short answer is because it is often inconvenient to do so on short business trips

Comment: If this is your soluton, then please award it the answer, to help future readers. A great solution, btw (+1)

Answer (score 18):

I also use a safety razor. Any USA drug store will have 3 or 5 packs of really terrible [disposable razors](http://www.cvs.com/shop/personal-care/shaving/men-s-disposable-razors/gillette-sensor2-plus-pivot-men-s-disposable-razor-10ct-prodid-1010393), maybe $1.50 each razor. If you have a heavier beard than I do, you may need more than one for a single decent shave.

I've considered flying with an *empty* safety razor for vacation and buying a pack of blades at my destination, figuring I can use half of them before getting back on a plane. For short trips, I'm blessed with a job in an industry where appearance is ignored and a beard that's gone completely grey and harder to see.

Comment: Speaking as a grey-bearded UNIX sysadmin who turns 50 Real Soon Now, I had not previously considered how convenient my industry is in that regard!

Comment: more than one? I can eat through a 5 pack of these if I have more than a 3 days beard.... one pass and the blade doesn't do much anymore... (then again my beard is reeeeeally heavy)

Comment: I've considered this as well. The main downside is that it requires that I go shopping every time I arrive at my destination

Comment: My experience is similar to Andrew's.  I carry a Gillette travel tech in my carry on, with no blade of course. If I check a bag/box I put an envelope of blades in there. Otherwise, I forego shaving or buy at the destination, depending on the trip.  You can also usually get a single wrapped disposable at a drug store or sometimes at a hotel concierge/canteen.

Comment: @emmby I *like* going to groceries and drug stores in foreign countries, to check out the differences. But razor blades are very expensive in some of them.

Comment: I agree that shopping in international countries is fun, however many of my trips are short domestic travel for work where I have limited time to go explore/shop.

Comment: That link doesn't work consistenly - for me it says it's not available in my country.

Comment: It's just to a link for one of our major drug store's web store showing bad razor blades in a 10-pack. You didn't miss much.

Answer (score 13):

Would you consider purchasing a very cheap electic/battery razor, just for travel?

Not my personal choice, but they (sort of) get the job done and [cost from $7 on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank?keywords=electric+razor&fst=as%3Aon%2Cp90x%3A1&rh=n%3A3760911%2Ck%3Aelectric+razor&qid=1493801592&sort=price-asc-rank)

Comment: If the asker travels often, it might be worth investing some money in a nicer one. I prefer to shave with a blade but I'm very glad to have the electric (not a cheap one!) as a backup plan. You can easily shave with an electric almost anywhere, any time, so it comes in handy if you wake up late for work or something like that.

Comment: Yes, an electric is a good potential solution, thank you

Answer (score 8):

Storing them under mineral oil might work. It's a bit messy, but that's what people do in the lab to stop alkali metals oxidising in the air, so it should work for steel blades too. Failing that, keeping it in one of those vacuum food saver things might work.

I'm not sure how the moisturising strip on the blade will hold up to any of this though.

Comment: I do this with spearfishing knives to prevent them from rusting. Coat the blades in olive oil and you'll make them somewhat rust-resistant.

Comment: I am using Vaseline at home to make the blades last longer.  You can get small tubes that would be good for travel.  It's more viscous than mineral oil so I think it would be better for travelling.

Comment: I'm a big fan of submerging my blades (I used to use mineral oil but switched to rice) to keep them sharp. I do this with my daily razor, but doing it with a pack of cartridges I use rarely does seem messy and inconvenient. I had also thought about the vacuum sealer idea but wasn't certain about it enough to justify buying one just for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Moisture causes oxidation. Store your leftover blade cartridges in a sealed, airtight container with a desiccant.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. It wouldn't be hard for me to put a pack of razors in a jar or bag with rice or silicon desiccant pack

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have one, get yourself a leather belt. You can later invest in a proper strop but for now use this...

Hang the belt by the buckle on a door handle. Pull on the other end of the belt so its taut, then push the razor away from you (in the opposite direction that you would use it to shave) and do this several times

Your razor should be 'stropped' back to a degree of sharpness.

[This promotional video](https://youtu.be/Px2LZXGoeEw?t=40s) gives a good visual indicator of what I have just described.

Comment: You can 'strop' a disposable "Mach 3" razor?

Comment: @brhans That's what the linked video appears to show.

Comment: But this does nothing for the listed main problem of oxidation or corrosion.

Comment: @BenjaminKelley the question did ask about sharpness.  One would think the stropping process would also buss away the oxidation on the blade.  Apparently you can achieve a similar result using plain blue denim, that is pushing a razor across jeans.

Comment: @Criggie Indeed. I have seen that as a quick fix as well.

Comment: @Criggie fair enough, I guess it's interpretation of that could cause my difference of opinion there, but stropping a disposable blade would only remove oxidation/corrosion from the cutting and outer surface of a blade tho, leaving it free to deteriorate from any inaccessible exposed areas.

Answer (score 2):

They will probably last longer in a ziplock bag with a packet of moisture absorbant. Those come often with bags and stuff that is sensitive to moisture which is probably why your blades oxidize. Mine have almost never gone bad (even stored for 6 months or so in a travel pouch) since I live in a relatively dry place.

What I suggest though is to just finish the pack. Suppose you travel for 2 weeks with a 5-pack, you will probably use 3 blades during that time and if you continue to use them after you return, the pack would be finished in another week. It's the same thing with those small travel toothpaste tubes, otherwise you end up with a bunch of semi-used expired ones.